# Loop through sheets in a workbook by its file path

Tags: vba, excel

I want to print all the sheet names in a particular excel sheet. If I was doing it for the current workbook, this is how my code would be:

```
For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
      Debug.Print sht.Name
Next sht
```

I want to print the names of all the sheets present in a variable, say `sFilePath` which is the absolute file path of an excel file. How do I print the names of all the sheets in that excel file?

Comment: It's printing to the immediate window. Press Ctrl+G to show it in the VBA. Where do you want the names printed?

Comment: you are already doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to open that file before you get sheets names:

```
Dim sFilePath As String
sFilePath = Application.GetOpenFilename()
Workbooks.Open (sFilePath)

For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
      Debug.Print sht.Name
Next sht

'to close sFilePath workbook
ActiveWorkbook.Close False
```

Hope this help.

Comment: This code also opens the selected excel file. How do we avoid that?

Comment: You need to close it after you got sheet names.

Comment: Thanks, This is very close to what I wanted!

Answer (score 1):

to print file and sheets in a given directory:

```
    Sub Main()

    filePath = "C:\Users\jesse\Documents\ExcelTest\"     'folder to search
    currentFile = Dir(filePath & "*.xls*")
    Do Until currentFile = ""

        Debug.Print currentFile
        Set Workbook = Workbooks.Open(filePath & currentFile, False, True)

        For Each Sheet In Workbook.Sheets
            Debug.Print Sheet.Name
        Next Sheet

        Workbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
        currentFile = Dir
   Loop

    Set Workbook = Nothing

End Sub
```

Hope this solved your problem. cheers!

Comment: I was hoping if there's a way to do this without opening the file ( the file doesnt pop up on the screen)?